# Main navigation in sidebar - which semantic tag to use?

Tags: html, navigation, nav, semantic-markup

I am stuck in choosing what to use for sidebar navigation. Here is the structure:

```
<header>
</header>

<main>
   <nav-tag>
   </nav-tag>

   <article>

   </article>

   <aside>

   </aside>
</main>
```

The `aside` tag shows content related to `article`. So it's pointless to use it for a sidebar navigation. Should I add a `div` tag with id #sidebar and put a `nav` tag in it? Or should I just add a `nav` tag with id #sidebar and put the sidebar styles for it? I want to choose latter because without a style it semantically makes sense as its a container that stores an unordered list of links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it navigation? If yes, use `nav`. It doesn’t matter in which way the navigation is *displayed* (sidebar, header, footer, hidden, …).

If it’s the navigation for the whole site, don’t place it in `main`.

If it’s the navigation for the specific `article` only (e.g., a table of contents, or a list to separate article parts), place the `nav` as child of the `article`.

Side note: If the `aside` is related to the article (instead of the page), it might make sense to include it as child of `article`. If it doesn’t belong in the `article`, it should probably also not be placed in `main`. But all this depends on the actual content and your understanding of it.

Comment: Thank you for the help about the navigation but I got a little confused about aside being not placed in the main tag. My aside will be like a sub menu. E.g if a user views an event, he will see a right menu that will show list of all events just because he is in the "events controller", I hope it made sense. Where should I use aside then?

Comment: @Gasim: In that case, the `aside` should not be a child of `article` and not be a child of `main`, as I guess the main content of the page would be the specific event, without the list of links to all events.